# Implementing log off in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a classic asp application in which user logs in using NTLM authentication once done he will be validated and i have server varialbel LOGON_USER with his user name. Now i am trying to implement log off but the problem is the value LOGON_USER is never empty even if i end session.I cleared cache too but unable to it. Any suggestion on how to acheive this. My logoff page code.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Expires = -1

Session.Abandon
Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized"
Response.AddHeader "WWW-Authenticate","NTLM"
Response.Redirect "test.asp"
Response.End

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are doing a `Redirect` so any status you have set will be replaced in favor the the "302 Object moved" status the defines the function of redirect.

Also you need to understand the the LOGON_USER server variable is associated with TCP/IP Connection being used to make the request.  The only influence you have over this in ASP code is to add the "Connection" header with the value "close".  This will close this authenticated connection.  A new authenticated connection will only be made if you have turned off anonymous access or another page sends a 401 response.

However this control is limited because there can be multiple authenticated connections in use between the server and any single client.  A response to a request can only close the current connection not any of the others.

Comment: Any ideas on  how can i do this. I would like to kill user session and redirect him to home page once they click logoff button.

Comment: @user1296417:  How do you acheive "logon" in the first place?  What constitutes logon?  Does your site support anonymous access?